# How to split given string in line by line in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Consider the following string "google" . I want to split the following string as below using simple bash script. please help me out.

```
g
o
o
g
l
e
```

Comment: You really put a lot of effort into your question didn't you?

Comment: This my viva question. Please help me out Mitch if you can.

Comment: Perhaps you should help yourself by actually trying something...

Comment: Its urgent Mitch :/ Please help me

Comment: So urgent that you can't attempt it? Are you banned from google? CLOSE, CLOSE, CLOSE!

Comment: Please help me if you are a capable enough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that you will generally get a friendlier reception if you show what you've tried, or explain what you've thought about using and why it won't work.  Also, urgency is not recognized as a reason for demanding help here.  Claiming urgency is more likely to get your question ignored than answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution with fold :

```
echo "google" | fold -w1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It certainly helped me.